# Music Looping over eachother when you go back to original scene in Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have this piece of code in my didMove function which plays this track as soon as a player loads the app and is in the main menu.

```
self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("MusicFile", waitForCompletion: false))
```

It does play throughout all the scenes which is what I wanted. However whenever the player chooses to go back to the main menu, for e.g. from the gameOver scene back to the main menu, the music replays and the current one keeps going. I need the current one to keep going but not for the music to replay itself.

Comment: Your old scene stays alive, that is why it plays across multiple scenes

Comment: The issue isnt it playing across multiple scenes. The issue is whenever I go back to the scene with this line of code, it plays it again but over the music already playing.

Comment: please do not argue with me, what I told you is exactly the problem,  Music is not suppose to carry over when you go across scenes unless you explicitly move the node to different scenes. When you hit the menu scene again, you now have 2 menus in memory, which is why you get 2 sounds playing.